# How to find all wavs in a directory? JavaFX

Tags: file, javafx, filter

I'm trying to find all the wavs in every folder that I have in a directory, for example, "Music". Right now, my code shows the wavs found in whatever folder I select, but I want it to list all the wavs found in the whole directory at once, without the user going from folder to folder. How can I do that? Here's my code:

```
FileChooser chooseFile = new FileChooser();
FileChooser.ExtensionFilter filter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Choose a file (*.wav)", "*.wav");
    chooseFile.getExtensionFilters().add(filter);
    File file = chooseFile.showOpenDialog(null);
    directory = file.toURI().toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should use a `DirectoryChooser` to select a directory. You can use the NIO package to find the files:

```
DirectoryChooser chooser = new DirectoryChooser();
File directory = chooser.showDialog(null);
Path[] wavs = findWavs(directory);
```

```
private static Path[] findWavs(File directory) throws IOException {
    Path dir = directory.toPath();
    try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(dir, Integer.MAX_VALUE, (path, attributes) -> path.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".wav"))) {
        return stream.toArray(Path[]::new);
    }
}
```

If you need `File`s instead you could simply map the paths to files:

```
        return stream.map(Path::toFile).toArray(File[]::new);
```